# Pass IHttpClientFactory with other parameters to a service

Tags: c#, http, .net-core

I am sure I am doing this wrong, so would appreciate some feedback on my approach.

I have an API, and my API calls a third party API. I have created a class and method, that all my requests will go through, to the 3rd party API. I need to pass a token in the request to the third party API.

I register my HttpClient with the base address of the API, and then I have my `HttpRequestHandler` class, and I have a constructor which is:

```
public HttpRequestHandler(IHttpClientFactory httpClient, string username, string password)
        {
            _httpClient = httpClient;
            _userName = username;
            _password = password;
        }
```

But, I am unsure how to register this, as I cannot pass `IHttpClientFactory` to it.

I am passing the username and password, as I need to make a request to authenticate, to get a token, that will be included on all other requests. The reason I am doing this is, the token will only last minutes, so I will need to include one with each request, and I will need to get this. I cannot store a token anywhere.

Am I approaching this the wrong way?